# How to handle unsuccessful installation of a Shopify App?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, shopify

I am working on a rails app for Shopify. In case I try to install the app and some server issue occurs and all the things are not committed, then also the app starts showing up in list  of apps installed by the shop? How to avoid it? How do I let the app fully installed after successful commit of everything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a development shop to test your App. If the merchant installs your App and you mess up, you lose, not the merchant. They will just delete your App and likely never come back.

Once you can install successfully, you're pretty set. Unfortunately, once the oAuth process is running, Shopify declares the App installed for the merchant and hands off the final token for you to persist. Any error in that step leaves the App installed for the merchant, but not for you. Keep that step simple and you should be good for almost all installs.